# Job possibilities for dependent exempt visa

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, job-hunting

I got a job offer from UK who is sponsoring me exempt visa to me and my wife. Since its an exempt visa I need to know the possibility of my wife working there and if she be also relieved from tax like me.

Will it be hard to find job in this visa category since the company can't deduct tax from her salary?

Comment: In the US, dependents on the analogous visa see not tax exempt. I'm not sure how it works in the UK, however.

Comment: @phoog it's roughly similar. The spouse can work, but there's no relief from tax unless the organisation has an exemption from HMRC. The OP should simply ask his sponsor's Authorising Officer.